# Do JSON objects NEED to be properly formatted?

Tags: json

I applied for a job and got a little test to do. Its pretty simple but I have to deal with a JSON object they supplied which is NOT formatted correctly.

I wonder if this is ok (I am pretty new to JSON) or not? (OK meaning I can still use it as a standard JSON object).

Here is the JSON string:

```
{"title": "Carbon Market Trader EU",
    "link": "cmteu",
    "children": [
      {"title": "Analysis",
        "link": "analysis",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Daily Reports",
                "link": "daily",
                "children": [
                    {"title": "Forward",
                      "link": "fwd",
                          "children": [

                            {"title": "Morning Report", "link": "morning"},
                            {"title": "Benchmark", "link": "bench"}
                        ]}
            ]},
            {"title": "Weekly Reports",
                "link": "weekly",
                "children": [
                    {"title": "Forward",
                    "link": "fwd",
                    "children": [
                        {"title": "Weekly Report","link": "weekly"}
                    ]}
            ]},
            {"title": "Monthly Reports","link": "mth"},
            {"title": "Price Forecasts",
                "link": "pfc",
                "children": [
                    {"title": "Price Forecasts","link": "pfc"},
                    {"title": "Supply and Demand","link": "sad"}
            ]},
            {"title": "Policy Updates","link": "pup"},
            {"title": "Analyst Updates","link": "aup"},
            {"title": "Carbon Market Brief","link": "cmb"},
            {"title": "Report Library","link": "ml"},
            {"title": "Reuters Insider","link": "ri"},
            {"title": "Market Indicators",
                "link": "mi",
                "children": [
                    {"title": "Overview","link": "overview"},
                    {"title": "Breakdown",
                        "link": "breakdown"
                        "children": [
                            {"title": "Cross Commodity Indicators","link": "cci"},
                            {"title": "Technical Indicators","link": "ti"},
                            {"title": "Fundamental Indicators","link": "fi"},
                            {"title": "Information Indicators","link": "ii"}
                    ]}
            ]}
    ]},
    {"title": "Supply",
        "link": "supply",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Cap","link": "cap"},
            {"title": "Overview","link": "overview"},
            {"title": "Reserves","link": "reserves"}
    ]},
    {"title": "Demand",
        "link": "demand",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Emissions Forecast","link": "ef"},
            {"title": "Power and Heat Emissions","link": "phe"},
            {"title": "Industry Emissions","link": "ie"}
    ]},
    {"title": "Market Data",
    "link": "md",
    "children": [
        {"title": "Carbon",
        "link": "carbon",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Forward",
             "link": "fwd",
                "children": [
                    {"title": "EUA","link": "eua"},
                    {"title": "sCER","link": "cer"},
                    {"title": "RGA","link": "rga"}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"title": "Coal",
        "link": "coal",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Forward",
            "link": "fwd",
            "children": [
                {"title": "API-2","link": "api"}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"title": "Crude oil",
        "link": "crude",
        "children": [
            {"title": "Forward",
             "link": "fwd",
            "children": [
                {"title": "Brent","link": "brent"}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing that object to "eval()" - it fails.  Invalid JSON.
(I've got to admit to having a hard time seeing exactly why, though)

Comment: I used many online parses and it failed on them all. Was wondering if that was a problem or not. As it fails the eval method I guess it does matter so I will be sending an email back to the employer telling them the JSON wont work.

Comment: Yes, if it fails "eval()" then it's not consummable... It's conceivable that some json parser would be able to deal with it anyway, but it would be very poor design to count on that even if you found one that did.

Comment: Thank you. I have now sent a mail to the person who sent it to me and asked her to resend it or if I should just fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Please use http://jsonlint.com/.

This is not ok.

Comment: Yes I know it is not properly formatted hence the question. I was wondering if that mattered. I guess from your answer it does.

Comment: @PJK: it might be useful to explain exactly _why_ it's not ok.